# Run multiple postman collections using newman on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, postman, jenkins-groovy, newman

I am using the following commands in Jenkins Pipeline job:

```
sh "postman-combine-collections -f *.postman_collection.json -o out.collection.json"

sh "newman run out.collection.json -e apigee-${params.Environment}-environment.postman_environment.json"
```

It is always running the first collection only.

I am using Postman-combine-collections v1.1.0.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue while trying to run newman twice, one after another. I wanted to use two different environment files. The Jenkins job stops, if newman exits with a failure (exit code != 0).

If you use `-x` (`--suppress-exit-code`), the second run is executed. Unfortunately, this way the exit code of the first run is set to 0. Failing tests in the first run will not fail the Jenkins job.

Here is my solution:

```
sh """
    set +e

    newman run collection.json -e environment01.json
    if [ $? != 0 ]
    then
        newman run collection.json -e environment02.json
        exit 1
    else
        newman run collection.json -e environment02.json
    fi
"""
```

With explicitly defining "set +e", Jenkins continues on failure. If the exit code of the first run is non-zero, no matter what result the second run gets, Jenkins exits with return code 1. Though both runs are executed. If the first run succeeds, the second run will determine the result of the Jenkins job.